# Modal Pop up website in react not fitting on mobile screen

Tags: reactjs

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8KLa.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0C7n.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FEIR.jpg)

I am trying to make this pop up fit on mobile screen, it's working fine on a computer screen but as soon as i switch to mobile to pop position is off and too long to the point it lays on the other sections of the website, i tried setting the media query to max-width mobile screen of 480px but nothing is working! I would appreciate any help!